# No message is showing up in lambda log in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have an SQS queue that triggers a Lambda as soon as it gets a message. The lambda is getting triggered but I can't see any response when I use the receive_message API call.

```
import json
import urllib.parse
import boto3
sqs = boto3.client('sqs')


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    try:
        response = sqs.receive_message(
        QueueUrl="https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/*****/test-queue"
            )

        print("Response",response)
        return 
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise e
```

**Output**

```
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'd4d364b9-ac8c-5dcd-a174-33b4aae995c9', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'd4d364b9-ac8c-5dcd-a174-33b4aae995c9', 'date': 'Sun, 12 Apr 2020 12:05:57 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '240'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Can someone help me here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your lambda function being automatically triggered by `SQS`, then the message(s) will be in the `event` object.

You don't have to call `sqs.receive_message` explicitly to read messages from the queue. Just use the `event` object.